# Yii: How to get list of checkboxes?

Tags: php, web-applications, twitter-bootstrap, yii

I have a table called Table, it has `id` and `name` as attributes.

For each entry in Table, I would like to generate a checkbox.

How can I do this?

I am using the Yii-Boostrap plugin, which I'm expecting I would need use something like this:

```
foreach(...)
    echo $form->checkBoxRow($model, 'name');
```

Which I got from the [Yii-Bootstrap Documentation](http://www.cniska.net/yii-bootstrap/#tbActiveForm).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this simple one

And in this for precheck to work just pass the array as second parameter
as shown below

```
<?$select=array('2','3');?>

<?php echo CHtml::checkBoxList(
        'TableValues',
        '$select',//you can pass the array here which you want to be pre checked 
        CHtml::listData(Table::model()->findAll(),'id','name'),
        array('checkAll'=>'Select all tasks', 'checkAllLast'=>true)
    ); ?>
```

And you can get the selected checkbox values in the controller using

```
 print_r($_POST['TableValues']);
```

**UPDATED**

For this the precheck to work u have to assign the array to the model attribute as shown below

```
<?php $model->modelAttributename=array('3','5')//respective checked values as of yours 

<?php echo $form->checkBoxList(
            $model,
            'modelAttributename',
            CHtml::listData(Table::model()->findAll(),'id','name'),
            array('checkAll'=>'Select all tasks', 'checkAllLast'=>true)
        ); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks @Ninad, could I do something similar using `$form->...`? I'm trying to use the Yii Twitter Bootstrap extension you see.

Comment: Actually, Ninrod, I can't get pre-selected values to work. :( If I set the 2nd parameter to an array of values to be checked, I get an error: `strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string`, array given. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You should see your result array form sql query and see how to access any string you want from result array and then you create array of string that contain list of name.
e.g. your result query is $result["name"] = array("a","b","c");

```
<?php /** @var BootActiveForm $form */
    $form = $this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.TbActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'horizontalForm',
    'type'=>'horizontal',
    ));
?>    
<fieldset>

<legend>Legend</legend>

<?php    
    $result["name"] = array("a","b","c");     
    echo $form->checkBoxListRow($model, 'checkboxes', $result["name"]);
?>

</fieldset>
```

Comment: Thanks @cavaliercyber but what would `checkboxes` be here? Is this a variable in `$model`?

Answer (score 0):

Check this example:

Book Model:

```
'authors' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Author', 'authorbook(book_id,author_id)'),
```

Author Model:

```
'books' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Book', 'authorbook(author_id, book_id)'),
```

Checkbox List in form:

```
$books = CHtml::listData(Book::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name');
$selected_keys = array_keys(CHtml::listData( $model->books, 'id' , 'id'));
echo CHtml::checkBoxList('Author[books][]', $selected_keys, $books);
```